# How can I resolve DeadLock due to PageLock in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock, sql-delete

I have a table `adjustment_details_backup` in SQL Server. I have attached the schema for the table here:

```
+---------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
| Name                      | Owner   | Type       | Created_datetime        |
|---------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------|
| adjustment_details_backup | dbo     | user table | 2020-02-24 13:14:20.370 |
+---------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+

+---------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------+
| Column_name   | Type     | Computed   | Length   | Prec   | Scale   | Nullable   | TrimTrailingBlanks   |
|---------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------+
| id            | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         | (n/a)                |
| cid           | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         | (n/a)                |
| promotion_id  | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         | (n/a)                |
| adjustment_id | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         | (n/a)                |
| target_type   | varchar  | no         | 10       |        |         | no         | no                   |
| target_ids    | nvarchar | no         | -1       |        |         | no         | (n/a)                |
| bf_ids        | nvarchar | no         | -1       |        |         | yes        | (n/a)                |
+---------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+----------------------
 
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| index_name                     | index_description                                     | index_keys        |
|--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------|
| adj_details_backup_cid_pid_idx | clustered                                             | cid, promotion_id |
| PK__adjustme__3213E83EAF725CC9 | nonclustered, unique, primary key, stats no recompute | id                |
| UQ__adjustme__32324848CA673053 | nonclustered, unique, unique key                      | adjustment_id     |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

[schema for adjustment_details_backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOoCC.jpg)

This table contains multiple records for a promotion Id. I am facing a deadlock between the queries being executed concurrently.

Query 1:

```
delete from adjustment_details_backup 
where promotion_id = 28492
```

Query 2:

```
delete from adjustment_details_backup 
where promotion_id = 28260
```

XML for deadlock graph is:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process26ce2575848" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process26ce2575848" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1643475 " waittime="19306" ownerId="5395124916" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" XDES="0x26cbb4f7aa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="6" kpid="138164" status="suspended" spid="367" sbid="0" ecid="7" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.177" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.177" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-twgm5" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5395124916" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x0200000005301203bd2a6100166b96a8b076cf61b9cf61140000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28260   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process26ce2577c28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1666487 " waittime="19302" ownerId="5395124916" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" XDES="0x26077e2daa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="8" kpid="97276" status="suspended" spid="367" sbid="0" ecid="6" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.177" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.177" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-twgm5" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5395124916" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x0200000005301203bd2a6100166b96a8b076cf61b9cf61140000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28260   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process26cc0b25848" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1992058 " waittime="19296" ownerId="5395124916" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" XDES="0x25e78a15aa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="10" kpid="86452" status="suspended" spid="367" sbid="0" ecid="5" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.177" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.177" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-twgm5" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5395124916" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x0200000005301203bd2a6100166b96a8b076cf61b9cf61140000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28260   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process26220db44e8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1644155 " waittime="19306" ownerId="5395124916" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" XDES="0x2629d0ddaa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="11" kpid="93408" status="suspended" spid="367" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.240" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:57:20.177" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.177" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-twgm5" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5395124916" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x0200000005301203bd2a6100166b96a8b076cf61b9cf61140000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28260   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process263301e48c8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="391" schedulerid="8" kpid="24256" status="suspended" spid="208" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.873" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-bck7r" hostpid="0" loginname="sfadmin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5394851450" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000add9d836abdc925b7e8512a0ad07c77bad20f63f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28492   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process2613e78b468" taskpriority="0" logused="63080" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1666487 " waittime="12485" ownerId="5394851450" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" XDES="0x26ccec03aa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="82200" status="suspended" spid="208" sbid="0" ecid="4" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.873" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-bck7r" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5394851450" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000add9d836abdc925b7e8512a0ad07c77bad20f63f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28492   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process26cc9927468" taskpriority="0" logused="63080" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1992058 " waittime="12580" ownerId="5394851450" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" XDES="0x26ca371daa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="9" kpid="67304" status="suspended" spid="208" sbid="0" ecid="6" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.873" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-bck7r" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5394851450" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000add9d836abdc925b7e8512a0ad07c77bad20f63f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28492   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process26ce204a8c8" taskpriority="0" logused="63080" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1643475 " waittime="12946" ownerId="5394851450" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" XDES="0x26cc3125aa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="95516" status="suspended" spid="208" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.873" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-bck7r" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5394851450" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000add9d836abdc925b7e8512a0ad07c77bad20f63f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28492   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process26cc9933848" taskpriority="0" logused="63080" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:1644155 " waittime="12856" ownerId="5394851450" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" XDES="0x26b35c0baa0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="7" kpid="72952" status="suspended" spid="208" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastbatchcompleted="2021-04-12T22:55:00.873" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.873" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-bck7r" hostpid="0" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5394851450" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000e3619d1890952212a37333bffa6d0ca92cc3684c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9c39d2d962cc226f" queryplanhash="0x3a3f2196dc34ec92" line="1" stmtend="126" sqlhandle="0x02000000add9d836abdc925b7e8512a0ad07c77bad20f63f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 28492   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1643475" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock26a2ff11d80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process26cc9933848" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26ce2575848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1666487" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock26a3208a300" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process263301e48c8" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26ce2577c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1992058" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock266cdfce800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process263301e48c8" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26cc0b25848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1644155" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock26a316db580" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2613e78b468" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26220db44e8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <exchangeEvent id="Pipe26268814400" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Coordinator" nodeId="6" tid="0" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process26ce204a8c8" />
        <owner id="process26cc9933848" />
        <owner id="process2613e78b468" />
        <owner id="process26cc9927468" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process263301e48c8" />
      </waiter-list>
    </exchangeEvent>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1666487" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock26a3208a300" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process26ce2577c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2613e78b468" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1992058" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock266cdfce800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process26cc0b25848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26cc9927468" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1643475" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock26a2ff11d80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process26ce2575848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26ce204a8c8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1644155" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" id="lock26a316db580" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594139574272">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process26220db44e8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26cc9933848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

**QUERY EXECUTION PLAN**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWOtv.png)

**Screenshots for DEADLOCK GRAPH:**

[deadlock_graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBaEi.png)

[deadlock_graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFsub.jpg)

[deadlock_graph 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEBVA.png)

According to my analysis, the deadlock is due to multiple records for different promotion Id residing on the same page. How do I prevent this deadlock?

Also, since both the queries are using same filter parameter .v.i.z. `promotion_id`. I am assuming that query #1 will take a lock and if records for query #2 are contained on the same page, then it would wait for the lock by query #1 to be released. Why is this not the case?

If the page lock has been acquired by one resource, why is the other not waiting for that pagelock to be released? Does the PageLock not handle concurrent DML queries efficiently?

Comment: Don't use images like that, it's useless to us. Paste in the text of the table and index definitions instead.

Comment: Looks like you need an index on `promotion_id`

Comment: @Charlieface pasted the schema . How will adding an index to promotion_id help . How will it work internally and resolve the conflict . Also , should it be a clustered or a non-clustered index would work?

Comment: NCI should be fine, I think it's just locking much too much because of no index. Are there any other queries in the same transaction or is it just the one? Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: It's also possible for Sqlserver to deadlock on parallel threads, I see your plan is parallel try using `maxdop 1` hint see if that has any impact.

Comment: @Charlieface Please find the query plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkBQ9piUd.  Also please give me the reason why should adding an index on promotion_id work for me .

Comment: It's doing a massive parallel scan of the whole table to find the row to delete, then it is going to the clustered index to do the delete, then going back to the other indexes to delete from there. So the parallel scans of the table may be in any order, and are clashing with each other. One possible solution is to prevent parallelization `maxdop(1)`, but then your delete will be slow. The real solution is to add an NCI on `promotion_id`